# LESS with less.php undefined variable error

Tags: php, css, variables, less, undefined

So pretty simple question. I'm getting this error;

```
Lessc error: variable @base-path is undefined in file /<domain root>/assets/less/default_skin/theme_settings.less in theme_settings.less on line 9, column 9 07
```

(domain root blocked out)

However, line 1 to 9 of `theme_settings.less` is this;

```
// Define base file path
// ----------------------------
@base-path: "../base";


// Define included Animations
// ----------------------------
@import "@{base-path}/animate.less"; // core animation styles
```

Basically what it's saying is that `@base-path`, which is defined right before it's used, does not exist.

I checked that the file encoding is UTF-8 without BOM and all other solutions I could find are irrelevant here.

I really have no idea how it could not be defined. I tried retyping the lines and also tried copying the example off the LESS website and changing it to the above pretty much.

Comment: I'm a little rusty with LESS, but shouldn't it be: `@import "@base-path/animate.less";`

Comment: No, look at [this](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-import-statements) section on the LESS docs

Comment: The code is ok, I can't reproduce the error. Can you give more information?

Comment: @blonfu I'm using [oyejorge/less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php) after lessc.php gave me errors because the less files I'm using include extend stuff. Can't find any related issues on their github either.

Comment: Try removing the hyphen in the name and replacing it with underscore, might be lessphp dislikes hyphens in variable names

Comment: Check whether lessphp compiler is the same as a less compiler, old less compiler did not allow variables inside imports, so that could also be an issue here. It seems to work for me in the edit me section on http://leafo.net/lessphp/ though.

Comment: Will try removing the hyphen to see if that fixes it there, but that shouldn't be a problem. Also leafo lessc has no problem with this file but runs into issues with newer less stuff because it hasn't been updated in a while